# Delete file from upload path with database table

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, delete-file

I done delete image url from database with following code, but is not delete file image from upload path, how can delete file from upload path with url it in database (both together)?

This php is just for delete url from database:

```
$delete = $this -> input -> post('checked');
foreach($delete as $val) {
    $this - > db - > delete($this - > _table, array('id' = > $val));
}
```

**Update:**

I have error in use of following code.

```
$id = '166';
$query = $this - > db - > get_where('hotel_image', array('id' = > $id));
if ($query - > num_rows() > 0) {
    $res = $query - > row();
    unlink(base_url(uploads/$res - > images));//This is line 161
}
$this - > db - > delete('hotel_image', array('id' = > $id));
```

Error:(my images are in this pach: `http://example.com/uploads/`)

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Use of
>   undefined constant uploads - assumed 'uploads'
>  Filename: user/dence.php
>  Line Number: 161
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message:
>   unlink() [function.unlink]: http does not allow unlinking
>   Filename: user/dence.php
>  Line Number: 161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**unlink()**](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete a file from disk, just pass the filename as parameter.

> bool unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] )
>
> Deletes filename. Similar to the Unix C unlink() function. A E_WARNING
>   level error will be generated on failure.

Something like (this is simplified code. You might want to check the path from DB is complete or else add the rest.):

```
$delete = $this -> input -> post('checked');
foreach($delete as $val) {
    $this->db->select('images')->from($this->_table)->where('id',$val);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      $res = $query->row();
      $file = './uploads/'.$res - > images));
      // echo $file;  #check if this is the correct path!
      @unlink($file);
    }
    //now query to delete
    $this -> db -> delete($this - > _table, array('id' = > $val));
}
```

Comment: I have error in use this function, please see update in my first post and tell me !!?

Comment: @EmmyCharles edited my answer. You were not building the path right. UPDATE: also, if you use a full path, check if your INI settings allow it. In case (I re-corrected my answer) use a relative path